# Docker-Compose messing up Volume Bindings

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I tried to start a docker-compose envorinment for a webapp i want to write, but now im searching and trying to figure out why docker is messing up the Volume Binding!?!

Sorry not enough Reputation for embedding the image

[Why is there the Project Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE2Fp.png)

```
Projectroot: E:\workspace\PHPStorm
|- app/
|- Images/
|  |- BaseMeWebServer
|     |- Dockerstuff /Dockerfile
|- docker-compose.yml
```

In the docker-compose.yml I setup the volumes like:

```
volumes:
  - ./app:/var/www/site
```

I tryed to reinstall docker, deinstall docker an search in the regestries also in all directorie for docker and deleted all entrie to reinstall a clean docker but this doesnt fixed my problem.
I searched for .json files with docker configs and doesn't found the right one.

At least I tryed it on my other machine and it worked without any Problems, so my Project isn't the Problem...

Has anybody ideas how i can fix this error?

Comment: i dont understand your question... what do you want?

Comment: I want to bind my app/ to /var/www/site like its shown in the screenshot, but docker builds my composefile with:
_E:/workspace/PHPStorm_**host_mnt\e\......**
but thats wrong the first part should not be there, the local path should be something like:
**host_mnt\e\workspace....**